# Edit text and href attribute of same element depending on different condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the code below to satisfy different conditions but it seems very repetitive. Is there a way I can edit the #nav-link element's text and href attribute dynamically without having to write out `$('#nav-link').text('___').attr("href", "/___");` 3 times to make the code simpler and more readable?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('colors') > -1) {
  $('#nav-link').text('Colors').attr("href", "/colors");
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf('cars') > -1) {
  $('#nav-link').text('Cars').attr("href", "/cars");
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf('people') > -1) {
  $('#nav-link').text('People').attr("href", "/people");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
["colors", "cars", "people"]
  .forEach(x => window.location.href.indexOf(x) > -1 && 
    $('#nav-link').text(x).attr("href", "/" + x))
```